# Fixing "Position: Absolute" for mobile

Tags: css

So I made an entire website using percentage and VW font sizes to make the website not change on like zooming in and making the window bigger/smaller. There was a few parts where I have to overlay images on top of each other and I achieved this by using "Position: Absolute" those parts are my nav bar, and my 2 "Subscribe to our mailing list" input boxes.

The site works absolutely perfect, except when you get to right around the width of a mobile device (I don't know, maybe like 300 pixels?) then all the positioning goes wonky.

This is my CSS for the nav bar: http://pastebin.com/raw/QpjPiN4Z

I was wondering if there was some sort of way I could change the positioning somehow where it doesn't affect the rest of the website? Or maybe use media queries somehow to aid in fixing it? I have no idea what to do. Everytime I change the "Position:" type, it breaks, badly.

Comment: Use media queries, no doubt. A recommendation, use more classes in your tags instead ids.

Comment: Please show *complete*, minimal, markup which reproduces the problem. A bunch of CSS is often *useless* without also seeing the HTML structure, especially with everything is directly selected int he CSS. There's no way to tell what may be nested in what.

Comment: @Scott view-source:http://towerduel.com/test/ view-source:http://towerduel.com/test/css/main.css

Comment: I am not going to scour your markup to find your problem. Please post relevant code here which reproduces the issue. If you don't want to make the effort, I'm certainly not going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Cesar suggested, use media queries in your CSS for overrides. Specify the pixels you want to do overrides.

```
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 300px) {
 // Do css overrides here
}
```

Manipulate the min/max pixel width for your overrides, then just start doing CSS. If you run into a style that won't override do something like this:

```
.container { height: 500px !important; }
```

The !important flag will override things don't seem to want to let you override them. It can come in handy when you're near losing your mind. Use chrome/firefox Inspect Element to help you along the way.